# find circular transactions in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in sql server database in which records of transactions are stored. Table consists of user id of buyer and user id of seller of product. I have to find the circles in the table for example-

I have to get the records of type- A sells to B, B sells to C, C sells to D AND D sells to A.

Please help.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're doing lots of these kinds of queries, you might be more happy with a graph database such as [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/)

Comment: No I Can't change the database.

Comment: Not change. Just export the data and run that particular sort of query in another database. I don't know your use-case, of course, but these kinds of hierarchical / recursive queries don't perform well in SQL.

Comment: Related (but not strictly T-SQL specific, thus not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398010/finding-cycles-in-directed-graphs-using-sql

Comment: Is there a limit to how many hops?  And is this per-product, or just in general?  In the latter case, if your dataset is large enough (comprises enough people/companies), I'd actually expect it to return **everybody**.

Comment: no there is no limit, I have to find all circles of each length. And no product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckIsCircular(@SellerId INT) 
RETURNS BIT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsCircular BIT = 0
    DECLARE @Sellers TABLE(Id INT)
    DECLARE @TempSellers TABLE(Id INT)
    DECLARE @Buyers TABLE(Id INT)

    INSERT INTO @TempSellers(Id)VALUES(@SellerId)

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TempSellers)BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM @Sellers s
                  INNER JOIN @TempSellers t ON t.Id = s.Id)BEGIN
            SET @IsCircular = 1
            BREAK;
        END
        INSERT INTO @Sellers(Id)
        SELECT Id FROM @TempSellers

        INSERT INTO @Buyers(Id) SELECT BuyerId FROM YourTable
        DELETE @TempSellers
        INSERT Into @TempSellers(Id)
        SELECT YourTable.SellerId
        FROM YourTable
        INNER JOIN @Buyers ON [@Buyers].Id = YourTable.SellerId
    END

    RETURN @IsCircular
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a graph traversal challenge; this is not natively supported in TSQL, but you can [simulate it](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html).

Comment: Actually I have a table in which about 10 million transaction data is stored. So can you suggest how to process this data to get these circular transaction

Answer (score 0):

This is a skeleton how I do it in Teradata, so syntax must be slightly modified for SQL Server:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (..., Path, isCycle) AS
(
  SELECT
     ...
    ,',' || CAST(seller AS VARCHAR(1000)) || ',' AS path
    ,0 AS isCycle
  FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      ...
     ,cte.Path || cte.buyer || ',',
     ,case when cte.Path LIKE '%,' || TRIM(tab.buyer) || ',%' then 1 else 0 end
    FROM cte, tab 
      WHERE cte.buyer = tab.seller
      AND cte.isCycle <> 1
)
SELECT ...
   ,Path || Destination
   ,isCycle
FROM cte
WHERE isCycle = 1
```

Build a materialized path of the graph while traversing and check if the next buyer is already in this path.

Comment: @Lukas Eder: As I wrote, it's Teradata syntax and must be slightly modified, but SQL Server supports recursive CTEs and changing **||** to **+** should be easy. Otherwise there's no kind of DDL provided.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the "Teradata", sorry about that. In fact, the `RECURSIVE` keyword caught my eye, which is not supported by SQL Server (it's implicit, in fact).

Answer (score -1):

With a recursive cte

```
declare @trans table (seller int, buyer int)

insert @trans 
values (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(1,5),(2,6),(3,5)

begin try

;with cte as
(
    select *, convert(varchar(500),'') as route from @trans
    union all
    select cte.seller, t1.buyer, convert(varchar(500),route + CONVERT(varchar(5),t1.seller))  from cte  
        inner join @trans t1 on cte.buyer = t1.seller

) 

    select * from cte
    where seller=buyer
    option (maxrecursion 50)
end try
begin catch
    print 'loops'
end catch
```